# StoreKit Subscription with free trial not present in receipt after purchase (tx id off by 1)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, storekit

I offer a subscription in my application, and after purchase I validate that transaction against the receipt to get its expiration date. I do this by loading the receipt from disk, sending it to Apple for validation/ decryption (I know this is bad practice), and then iterating over the `latest_receipt_info` in the JSON response looking for a transaction matching the `transactionIdentifier` of the `SKPaymentTransction` object.

This works for most subscriptions, but not those offered with a free trial/ introductory offer. Please take a look at my example below:

1. I purchase a subscription that is returned to my application with a `transactionIdentifier` of `1000000506350685` and `originalTransaction.transactionIdentifier` of `null`.
2. I get the latest JSON receipt from Apple whose latest entry is one matching my product identifier and timestamp, but the `transaction_id` is `1000000506350686` and so is `original_transaction_id`.

Therefore I am unable to validate the purchase.

There are no problems when purchasing a subscription **without** a free trial/ introductory offer. There are no other objects in the returned receipt that matches the transaction id returned to my application.

This is in the sandbox environment, I am not sure about the behavior in production.

Has anyone had any similar experiences? What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is probably due to the fact that you've already purchased that product before in Sandbox, and there's no device receipt in sandbox until you make a purchase (unlike production).

Either way, what you should be looking at is the latest `product_id` and `expiration_date` from the receipt to validate if the subscription is active. Transaction IDs can be keys for your transactions if you're saving them in a database, but shouldn't be used to validate a purchase.

Here is a really good blog post that goes over what your in-app purchase server should be doing to validate and keep subscription status up-to-date: [iOS Subscriptions are Hard](https://medium.com/revenuecat-blog/ios-subscriptions-are-hard-d9b29c74e96f)

> I do this by loading the receipt from disk, sending it to Apple for
>   validation/ decryption (I know this is bad practice).

This is actually the [recommended approach](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html) by Apple.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I still don't fully understand why having purchased the product in the sandbox before somehow offsets the transaction IDs in the receipt when purchasing a product with an introductory offer, but I will change the logic to look for *either* matching tx id *or* product id plus transaction date.

What I meant by the latter is that I'm sending the receipt directly to apple for validation/ decryption from the device which is susceptible to man-in-the-middle attacks. Eventually I want to host my own server for this (or use RevenueCat!), but for now it's easiest.